# How to add Genre Artwork into UITableViewCell in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, media-player, mpmediaitem

I am trying  to add `Genre` Artwork into my `UITableViewCell` in iOS like following pic.

[image]

I think there is no built-in artwork for `Genre`.
I am using `MediaPlayer Framework` and i can add `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork`.
But i have no idea how to add Genre artwork.

How can i do it? Any Ideas are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search through all available songs, pull out the **MPMediaItemPropertyGenre** string.

From there you could get the list of available genres and then you could either have your own custom artwork for the genre or you could get a random album artwork from a song in that genre using **MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork**.

Note this is untested code. In your cellForRowAtIndexPath do something like this.

```
MPMediaItem *mItem = (MPMediaItem *)[rockSongs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

MPMediaItemArtwork *artWork = [mItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

cell.imageView.image = [artWork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];
```

If you want to add your own custom artwork you could just set the cell image.

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rock"];
```

Comment: any sample code bro. Yes i am using PropertyGenre and all fine. Just want to add artwork. thz bro

Comment: @X-Developer-X I have edited my answer to add some sample code.

Comment: But how can i choose each row for each custom Image bro?I have alot of Genre artwork like Anime,Rock,HipHop,Country,etc. How can i add these artwork for custom row?

Comment: If you name your custom images the same as the string returned from the MPMediaItemPropertyGenre property you could in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method use the imageNamed method providing the MPMediaItemPropertyGenre string as the argument. This would give you the custom image for that genre and then just set the image of the cell to that image.

Answer (score 0):

**I give you to basic ideas for how to add this types of Art as you need.**

It is custom `UITableViewCell`, it is consist of **3 controllers**

```
1) UIImageView (main Image)
2) UILabel 
3) UIImageView (for put cell BackGround Image)
```

All The Controllers add in `cell.contentView`
With Setting a `UITableViewCell` accessory type on some cell `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`.

Comment: Uh, I think he knows how to lay out the views. The question is asking how to obtain genre artwork.

Comment: yes bro @BoltClock you right. I know how to layout View. I am just asking about genre artwork.